# Possible to use PKCE without client_secret?

Tags: authlib

I'm trying to use PKCE with the authorization code flow. It seems like the auth code flow requires you to use HTTP Basic auth to send along client_id and client_secret (so you must store client_secret client-side somewhere). Is this true, or is it possible to use the auth_code/PKCE flow without having store client_secret in the code? On [this page](https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/implement-auth-code-pkce/overview/) from Okta, it says

```
Important: Unlike the regular Authorization Code Flow, this call does not require the Authorization header with the client ID and secret. This is why this version of the Authorization Code flow is appropriate for native apps.
```

So that makes it seem like it's possible to not need the client_secret in the auth_code flow.

However from my testing, it seems like the `create_token_response`  method requires the client_secret to be sent along, otherwise it raises an `Invalid Client` error. I don't understand the need of that client secret as the client holds a code verifier.

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented it on AWS Cognito, I imagine it should also work on Okta.

Maybe you haven't configured the client correctly. In Cognito I had to create a client without a client secret, so if you made one with a secret, maybe that's why it's breaking. Or just sent the wrong `clientId`.